# My code should be detecting if a string has currency symbols, but it will not detect £

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

My code is supposed to detect currency symbols, and execute code based on the result, but the code will not detect the '£' under any circumstances. Here is the relevant code:

```js
let requirements = [ "£", "$" ];
let mcontent = "$£50";
let y = 0;
for (let p = 0; p < requirements.length; ++p) {
    if (mcontent.includes(requirements[p])) {
        ++y;
    }
}
if (y == 1) {
    //this is considered success, only ONE currency symbol was detected. If mcontent = '$50' or '£50', we should be here.
} else {
    //this is considered failure, TWO or ZERO currency symbols were detected. In this scenario, I want the code to fail.
}
```

I'm aware this may not be the best way to code a function to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish, so I'm open for better ideas/fixes for what I already have.

Comment: What did you expect? You have two currency symbols in that string.

Comment: @hev1 I even answered the question by rewriting the code without noticing 

Comment: The issue is that it's not detecting the £ at all, even if it's '£50', which should count as success.

Comment: @SenseiMunchkin I cannot reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/qkL3zcyp/

Comment: It should be detecting 2 symbols, but it will not detect the £. y should equal 2, not 1.

Comment: `console.log(y)` before your if-statement, you will see `2`, not 1.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get 2.

Comment: OP, you don't return anything, or do anything inside of the `if / else` blocks. Is that the problem here?

Comment: Pound and USD at the same time will give 2 as output

Comment: Please add some description about what you expect

Comment: Easier to use a regex

Comment: @SenseiMunchkin what browser are you using (and version?)

Comment: Christian, I don't include what I have in the if/else blocks because they aren't relevant to my question. 

MohsenAlyafei, It will not. That's the issue I'm having

yash, I expect for y to equal 2 when there is both $ and £, y to equal 1 when there is only one symbol, and for y to equal 0 when there is neither.

Comment: @NickParsons This is a Node.js app for a Discord bot.

Comment: @SenseiMunchkin As several people have said, `y` equals `2` at the bottom of that catch block. You did not log `y` with `console.log(y)` or you would see 2. It will be a lot of trouble building a Discord bot without knowing how to log a value.

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/z648jrs0/

Comment: @SenseiMunchkin your issue isn't reproducible (on a nodejs server prints 2): https://repl.it/repls/WearableUnderstatedSets#index.js, you're missing details, please try and create a [mre] so people can help debug your code. You're also saying that `mcontent` is inputted by the user, make sure that the character you think is `£` which is inputted by the user is in fact the same as the one in your array.

Comment: The £ is the exact same sign used in the array.

Comment: I have ran the code tons of times, and yes, I've logged y. It outputs 1 every single time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most concise way to do this is to check with `RegExp` like this:

```js
if (mcontent.match(/£|\$/g)?.length == 1) { // the question mark is so we don't encounter an error if no matches were found
  // success
} else {
  // failure
}
```

Here's a live example:

```js
const mcontent1 = '$£50';
const mcontent2 = '£50';
const mcontent3 = '$50';

const regex = /£|\$/g; // slash to escape $ because it has special meaning in regex

console.log(mcontent1.match(regex).length == 1); // false
console.log(mcontent2.match(regex).length == 1); // true
console.log(mcontent3.match(regex).length == 1); // true
```

Comment: Would there be a way to dynamically change the regex based on the requirements array?

Comment: @LeaftheLegend asked the exact same question I had. The requirements are wrote in a JSON file, and I'll need the regex to work with whatever I input there.

Comment: Yes.  `const regex = new RegExp(requirements.join('|').replace('$', '\\$'), 'g')`.  Since `$` has special meaning in `RegExp`, it has to be escaped with a slash.  And since a slash has special meaning in strings, the slash itself has to be escaped with a slash.

Comment: You could also just put the currency symbols in a character class like `new RegExp("[" + ['$','£'].join('') + "]")`.  If you aren't limited to a set of currency symbols and wanted to allow any of them, you could simply use `/\p{S}/`

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know that.  This should be the correct answer.  Use `/\p{S}/g` as the value of `regex` if you allow any currency symbol.

Comment: Wait, howcome `'$3.50'.match(/\p{S}/g)` evaluates to `null`?

Comment: Hm... It looks like JavaScript might not support unicode ranges.  That sucks.  JavaScript is always a bit behind in the regex department.  Anyway, if you want to check out the ranges, this is a good resource: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: But here it is in action, just to prove I'm not lying ;-)  https://regex101.com/r/SSRbg9/1/

Comment: Ah!  I have to add the `u` flag.  So the correct regex is `/\p{S}/gu`.  I had also seen it work at that website, which is why I was confused.

Comment: They're not relying on the browser's regex engine to do that.  They also let you do lookbehinds, which javascript doesn't unanimously support (and even what little we got is pretty recent).  If you notice, they even let you pick different regex engines.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex, just check if the string includes a symbol, increment a counter, and return whether or not there was exactly 1 match:

```js
let testA = "$£50",
    testB = "£50",
    testC = "$50";

function checkString(str) {
  const symbols = ["£", "$"];
  let matches = 0;

  for (const symbol of symbols)
    if (str.includes(symbol)) matches++;
      
  return matches == 1;
}

console.log(
  checkString(testA),
  checkString(testB),
  checkString(testC)
);
```

Comment: The mcontent variable is inputted by the user, for the sake of the example I put it in myself. This would not work in my scenario, and I need the .includes() function to work.

Comment: @SenseiMunchkin Huh? If it's inputted by the user, then you can just pass it to `checkString`. That's how I called it with multiple different inputs at the bottom.

Comment: Also @SenseiMunchkin, this answer implements `String.includes`, so I'm confused by that comment as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use RegExp it will return true or flase based on value entred
this example will give you an idea of how to use it

```js
const elementTwo = document.getElementById('elementTwo');
elementTwo.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  pattern = /^[£|$]{1}(\d+)/
  if (pattern.test(this.value)) {
    console.log("found")
  } else console.log("not found")

});
```

```html
<p>Enter value</p>
<input id="elementTwo" type="text" />
```

Comment: The point is that they want it to return false only if there is _exactly one_ currency symbol

Comment: @LeaftheLegend thank you for clarifying, I probably misunderstood